# Image and table in one line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image, html-table

I have an image 500px (width) and table 500px (width) (table is from bootstrap).

I want to make image and table show in one line, but table goes under image.

Comment: Show us the css and html that you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/MnVSg/)</kbd>

Here's a simple example showing an `IMG` and `TABLE` inline. `display: inline-block;` is used to put the elements on the same line as each other, but you need to be aware of two side effects of using inline-block.

First, white space (spaces, tabs, newline characters) between inline-block elements are rendered in the output. Think of inline-block elements as words. If you put spaces between words, it will render the space. To offset this, you can use a negative margin on the second element, or simply remove any white space between the two elements in your HTML.

Second, inline block elements can have a vertical-alignment property set. This is great if you want the two elements to be vertically aligned to the middle of each other. However, if you want the elements to be on the same height, you have to explicitly set `vertical-align: top;` in your CSS.

Because you're using Bootstrap, the width on the `TABLE` will also be set to 100%. You can set an explicit width for the `TABLE`, or return the element to the default "grow as much as you need" by setting `width: auto;`

Tables will also grow to fit the content inside of them. Bootstrap solves this by setting `max-width: 100%;` in the CSS. Make sure to also define a max-width, or use `table-layout: fixed;` on the tables when setting a width.

Comment: +1 for linking to a jsFiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer (based on limited information from the OP) is to use `display: inline-block` for the table and image.

An alternative would be to place the image in an extra column (or as a background to the column) of the table.